# how can I share a link on facebook with my universal app 10?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, uwp

I'm trying to share links on Facebook with my windows universal app 10 (c#), but i can't find any documentation on the subject. All of them are outdated using the windows 8 share charm.

I tried this but I don't want to share the link through the browser.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http:// "link to share")
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: what type of app do you have.. can you be more specific..? can you show us what you have tried on your own.. you need to be a little bit more specific / clearer in regards to what you want. what type of links on Facebook are you wanting to share your links..? FaceBook does have an `API` have you checked into that..?

Comment: My app is universal windows app c#. My autentification to facebook works . But there is nothing about sharing to facebook on msdn. 
I tried this : await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= "link to share")  
but this takes me to the browser .

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post

Comment: thx, I'll check the facebook api

Answer (score 3):

The [Windows SDK for Facebook](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/14/windows-sdk-for-facebook/) includes Facebook Authorization, Like, Graph and other Facebook functionality for Windows apps. Code and samples are available on github at https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb . Documentation is at http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb

With that library you can use the FBSession.ShowFeedDialogAsync method to let the user share a link with a title and description to their feed. See http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/#feed_dialog for a code snippet demonstrating this.

Comment: Thx a lot ! I already used the webauthentificationbroker to login to facebook. 
Do I have to switch to the login using windows fb sdk to use the ShowFeedDialogAsync ?

Comment: i tried to login using facebook sdk but I got : Invalid App ID: <..> . 

i used this appid to login with webauthentificationbroker and it works ! weired